# flaticon icons work when hosted locally but not working when online

Tags: css, html, icons, materialize

I have used a great number of icons on a website am working on. I set up the files very well and I can't seem to find a problem. I'm still a newbie.

Comment: have you tried using absolute paths instead of relative paths?

Comment: Am not familiar with that

Comment: Any link to understand absolute paths

Comment: Absolute path would like

url("http://www.domain.com/assets/css/styles.css")

Comment: Thanks for that .... turnt out I had capitalised the flaticon.eot/.woff... etc files

Comment: This question was (and is) in desperate need of a [mcve]. All questions here must describe the problem in the question itself, not by linking to it. The site is now dead anyway, illustrating why this rule is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have added those files and accessing them properly...

Your code for @font-face will be like this (path should be with or without 2 dots - depending upon its location), **I think font files names, you are hosting are in small case letters**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("../flaticon.eot");
    src: url("../flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: The @font-face was already present in the flaticon.css file. When i use the google developer tools i get a 404 error for the eot,woff etc files yet theyre present... Ia m very lost

Comment: @IanSamz its because you have used Flaticon.eot and other files with capitalize name instead of using flaticon ie. small caps letter. They are hosted in smallcaps...

use the above code which I have told you, it will work.

Comment: You are my hero... if I wasn't so broke I could have donated or sth .... thank you